# What wire should I use for a sauna 100' away from the panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to run a 220 line about 100ft from my breaker box to where the sauna be located.

The manual says for an 8 kw heater, 8-2 w/ground copper; 40 amp non GFCI breaker
But it also  says for distances “up” to 30 ft.....

So what if it’s 100?

[image]

Comment: Longer distances require larger wire to reduce voltage drop due to resistance. Have you looked at standard wiring charts for the correct size?

Comment: What size are the pumps?

Answer (score 1):

Having run a few of these calculations, the break point is usually a little past 100' if you want to hold voltage drop below 3%.   **However, for a resisitive heater, there is no reason** to hold voltage drop below 3%. It is a waste of money.

Regardless, 8000 *watts* happens at 33.33 *amps* on US 240V* voltage.  The UL-approved product instructions call for 8 AWG wire.  Southwire's voltage drop calculator tells me those conditions at 100' run yield 1.92% voltage drop on 8 AWG.

If the hot tub failed on 2% power drop, there is no way UL, CSA or TUV would list it.

You're all set.

---

* power was 110/220 when AC power was first mass marketed in 1915-ish, and the term stuck. Today,  US voltage is 120/240.  Except in Puerto Rico, where it's 0!

Comment: Agree but use a GFCI breaker .

Comment: @EdBeal definitely. But the instructions prohibit that, so use a GFCI deadface lol!   Unrelated, I've always wondered why hot tubs use resistive heaters and *not* heat-pump.  They'd be so much more efficient, and better yet, electricity would be nowhere near the water (it'd be a freon-water interchange). Though they'd become a motor load.